# ¿Cómo cifrar mensajes ? JAVA

Tags: java

Cifrar  mensajes:   consiste    en  que el  usuario ingrese un  mensaje y   a   continuación    indique un  número  entre   0   y   9   para    cada    vocal.  El  programa    debe    mostrar el  mensaje con la  codificación    de  vocales entregada   por el  usuario y   la  cantidad    de  vocales codificadas.    Por ejemplo,    si  el  mensaje ingresado   es: ESTA    ES  MI  PAUSA   ACTIVA  y   los números asignados   a   las vocales son,    en  su  orden:  4,  3,  6,  2,  8,  el  mensaje que mostrará    el  programa    será:   3ST4    3S  M6  P48S4   4CT6V4  se  han codificado  10  vocales .

Tengo esto pero no funciona.

```
String frase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese un mensaje ");

String num = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese un numero del 1 al 9 para cada vocal ");

    regexp = "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]";
    msj = frase.replaceAll(regexp, num);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolver tu problemita. Comente un poco el codigo para que sepas de que va cada ciclo y demas.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] listaNumeros = new int[5];
    char[] vocales = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
    int contVocales = 0;

    String frase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese un mensaje ");
    //Comvierte la frase a mayusculas
    frase = frase.toUpperCase();

    //Conteo de vocales
    char[] Arrayfrase = frase.toCharArray();
    for (char letra : Arrayfrase) {
        if (letra == 'A' || letra == 'E' || letra == 'I' || letra == 'O' || letra == 'U') {
            contVocales++;
        }
    }

    //Ciclo para introducir los disintos números
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese un numero del 1 al 9 para cada vocal "));
        listaNumeros[i] = num;
    }

    //Cada vocal es reemplazada por el orden en el que se ingreso los números
    for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
        frase = frase.replaceAll(String.valueOf(vocales[n]), String.valueOf(listaNumeros[n]));
    }

    String msj = frase + " se an codificado " + contVocales + " vocales";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msj);
}
```